# I have only one fragment and I want to change this fragment in viewpager dynamically according to recycler view item data

Tags: android, dynamic, android-viewpager, fragment, android-recyclerview

my problem is same as link given below
[I have a ViewPager by same fragments RecyclerView just load items in one fragment of ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53140134/i-have-a-viewpager-by-same-fragments-recyclerview-just-load-items-in-one-fragmenx#new-answer)
but at this post no one solve issue...
I have a recycler view items...I want when I click on recycler view item it takes me to viewpager fragment and shows that data of clicked item dynamically  and on swiping viewpager it should move previous and next fragment accordingly...under fragment I want to show data of recyclerrview item using single fragment...

I have done this by using multiple fragment and using multiple instances by different name and different layout name and different id for its recyclerView and it works but i have a large number of fragments and it is not the solution for me ):
   here is my viewpager code

```
    public class AndroidViewPagerExample extends FragmentActivity {
    ViewPager pager;
    int positionring;
    String rgtv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainuuuu);
        Intent it = getIntent();
        positionring = it.getIntExtra("POS", 0);
        final int position = it.getIntExtra("POS", 0);
       rgtv= it.getStringExtra("name");
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        pager.setPageTransformer(true, new RotateUpTransformer());
        pager.setCurrentItem(position);
        pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            Boolean first = true;
            Boolean userScrollChange=false;

            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                System.out.println("onPageScrollStateChanged");
                System.out.println("Current position=="+position);
               int curreentpos=position;
                int newpos=curreentpos+1;
                int previousState=curreentpos-1;
                if (previousState == pager.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING
                        && state == pager.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING)
                    userScrollChange = true;

                else if (previousState == pager.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING
                        && state == pager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
                    userScrollChange = false;

                previousState = state;


            }
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                System.out.println("onPageScrolled");



            }

            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // Check if this is the page you want.
                System.out.println("onPageSelected");
                Apples.newInstance(rgtv);
            }
        });

    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {

            return Apples.newInstance(rgtv);

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return ringtonelist.size();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
//        if (pager.getCurrentItem() != 36) {
//            pager.setCurrentItem(36);
//        } else {
        Vp_Ringtoneplaybtn.Playstop();
        super.onBackPressed();
        //  }
    }
}
```

code given below is adapter code

```
    public class RingToneAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RingToneAdapter.RingToneViewHolder> {
    public int mSelectedItem = -1;
    static MediaPlayer mp;
    View view;
    static Context rcntx;
    int oldpossssssss;
    List<RingTone_Items> ringtonelist;
    private TextView  hello, close;
    ImageView prev, next;
    private ImageView iconplay;
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    Dialog MyDialog;
   static final int[] resID = {R.raw.a48, R.raw.funny_hen, R.raw.funny_roster_1, R.raw.funny_roster_2, R.raw.rooster_1, R.raw.rooster_2,R.raw.rooster_3,R.raw.funny_cock,R.raw.a12,R.raw.a45,R.raw.a44,R.raw.a43,R.raw.a31, R.raw.a10,R.raw.chicken_1,R.raw.chick_2,R.raw.chick_3,R.raw.chick_4,R.raw.chick_5,R.raw.chick_6};

    public RingToneAdapter(Context rcntx, List<RingTone_Items> ringtonelist) {
        this.rcntx = rcntx;
        this.ringtonelist = ringtonelist;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RingToneViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(rcntx).inflate(R.layout.ringtone_values, viewGroup, false);
        RingToneViewHolder ringToneViewHolder = new RingToneViewHolder(view);
        return ringToneViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RingToneViewHolder ringToneViewHolder, final int i) {
        final RingTone_Items ringTone_items = ringtonelist.get(i);
        ringToneViewHolder.rtv.setText(ringTone_items.getRintonetv());
        if (mSelectedItem == i) { // mSelectedItem = -1 and at 1st time
            // there is no position selected...so the condition goes false...go
            // to else condtion
            ringToneViewHolder.iconplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_black_24dp);
        } else {
            ringToneViewHolder.iconplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_black_24dp); //  all icons will show play icon
        }
        ringToneViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // MyCustomAlertDialog(i);
                if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.reset();
                    mp = null;
                    ringToneViewHolder.iconplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_black_24dp);

                }
                //Intent it = new Intent(rcntx, ViewPager_Data.class);
                Intent it = new Intent(rcntx, AndroidViewPagerExample.class);
                it.putExtra("POS",i);
                it.putExtra("name",ringTone_items.getRintonetv());
//                mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(rcntx);
//                mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(rcntx.getResources().getString(R.string.ad_interstitial));
//                AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
//                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
//                mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
//                    public void onAdLoaded() {
//                        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
//                            mInterstitialAd.show();
//                        }
//                    }
//                });
                rcntx.startActivity(it);
            }
        });
        ringToneViewHolder.iconplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               if (mSelectedItem == i) {
                    mSelectedItem = -1;
                   oldpossssssss =  i;
                } else {
                    mSelectedItem = i;
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged(); //update the position of row...notifyDataSetChanged is bindview method
                if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) {

                    mp.stop();
                    //mp.deselectTrack(resID[i]);
                    mp.reset();
                    mp.release();
                    mp = null;

                    if (oldpossssssss == i) {

                    } else {
                       mp = new MediaPlayer();
                       mp = MediaPlayer.create(rcntx, resID[i]);
                       mp.start();
                   }
              } else {
                  // MyCustomAlertDialog(i);
                    mp = new MediaPlayer();
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(rcntx, resID[i]);
                    mp.start();
                }
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return ringtonelist.size();
    }

    class RingToneViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView rtv, hello, close;
        private ImageView iconplay;


        public RingToneViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            rtv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ringtitle);
            iconplay = itemView.findViewById(R.id.playicon);

        }

    }
    public void InterstitialAdmob() {
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(rcntx);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(rcntx.getResources().getString(R.string.ad_interstitial));
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                requestNewInterstitial();
            }
        });
        requestNewInterstitial();
    }
    protected void requestNewInterstitial() {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```

here is main activity code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RingToneAdapter adapter;
    public static ArrayList<RingTone_Items> ringtonelist;
    //final int[] resID = {R.raw.alert};
    public static int posss;
    private String[] fruitlist = new String[]{"Funny hen 1", "Funny hen 2", "Funny roaster 1", "Funny roaster 2","Funny roaster 3", "Funny roaster 4", "funny roaster 5","Funny cock", "Funny hen alarm","Abstracts", "Wake up",  "Funny tone","Get up","Alarm","Hen sound 1","Hen sound 2","Hen sound 3","Hen sound 4","Hen sound 5","Hen sound 6"};
    private boolean isFABOpen;
   FloatingActionButton fab,fab1,  fab3;
   FrameLayout fab2;
    AdView mAdView;
    RelativeLayout layout_no, layoutrateus, layout_yes, adlayout, adlayout1;
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private String fNmae = String.valueOf(R.raw.alarm);
    private String fPAth = "android.resource://packagename/raw/alarm";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (checkPermission()) {
                if (Settings.System.canWrite(MainActivity.this)) {
                    //setRingtone();
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS)
                            .setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()))
                            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }


                Log.e("value", "Permission already Granted, Now you can save image.");
            } else {
                requestPermission();
            }
        } else {
           // setRingtone();
            Log.e("value", "Not required for requesting runtime permission");
        }
        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
       //recyclerView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        recyclerView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
      //  RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager =
             //   new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        ringtonelist = getRingTone_Items();

        adapter = new RingToneAdapter(this, ringtonelist);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                RingTone_Items itemrg = ringtonelist.get(position);
                posss=position;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
            }
        }));

    }
  protected boolean checkPermission() {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    protected void requestPermission() {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Write External Storage permission allows us to do store images. Please allow this permission in App Settings.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.e("value", "Permission Granted, Now you can save image .");
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                        if (Settings.System.canWrite(MainActivity.this)) {
                          //  setRingtone();
                        } else {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS)
                                    .setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()))
                                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("value", "Permission Denied, You cannot save image.");
                }
                break;
        }
    }



    private ArrayList<RingTone_Items> getRingTone_Items(){
        ArrayList<RingTone_Items> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){

            RingTone_Items model = new RingTone_Items();

            model.setRintonetv(fruitlist[i]);
            list.add(model);
        }
        return list;
    }
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.pause();
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }
        onexit();
    }
    public void onexit() {
        android.view.LayoutInflater layout1 = android.view.LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View view1 = layout1.inflate(R.layout.backpress, null);
        final RelativeLayout relativeLayout=(RelativeLayout) view1.findViewById(R.id.layout_top);

        final AlertDialog.Builder gotoBuilder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        gotoBuilder1.setView(view1);
        final AlertDialog gotoDialog1 = gotoBuilder1.create();

        layout_no = view1.findViewById(R.id.layoutno);
        layoutrateus = view1.findViewById(R.id.layoutrateus);
        layout_yes =  view1.findViewById(R.id.layout_yes);
        layout_no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                gotoDialog1.dismiss();
            }
        });
        layoutrateus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    Intent mintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    mintent.setData(android.net.Uri.parse("market://details?id="
                            + getPackageName()));
                    startActivity(mintent);
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    try {
                        android.net.Uri uriUrl = android.net.Uri
                                .parse("https://market.android.com/details?id="
                                        + getPackageName());
                        Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                uriUrl);
                        startActivity(launchBrowser);
                    } catch (Exception e2) {
                        android.widget.Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "No Application Found to open link",
                                android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                gotoDialog1.dismiss();
            }
        });
        layout_yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
                gotoDialog1.dismiss();
                finish();

            }
        });

        gotoDialog1.getWindow().setLayout(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        gotoDialog1.show();

    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

this is my fragment

```
public class Apples extends BaseFragment{
    ImageView vpbtn;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    ImageView tvshare;
   static String s;
    static TextView  rgtname;
    int position = 0;
    private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.apple, container, false);
        vpbtn = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iconplaypause);
        mAdView = (AdView) v.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
       rgtname=v.findViewById(R.id.rgtname);
        rgtname.setText(s);
        tvshare=v.findViewById(R.id.tvshare);
        fab =   v.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab1 =  v.findViewById(R.id.frm1);
        fab2 =  v.findViewById(R.id.frm2);
        fab3 =  v.findViewById(R.id.frm3);

       // Vp_Ringtoneplaybtn.Setrintones(fab,fab1,fab2,fab3);
//        tvshare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//               Vp_Ringtoneplaybtn.shareapp();
//            }
//        });
        Vp_Ringtoneplaybtn.shareapp(tvshare);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(!isFABOpen){
                    showFABMenu();
                }else{
                    closeFABMenu();
                }
            }
        });
          Vp_Ringtoneplaybtn.Setrintones(fab1,fab2,fab3,position);
        vpbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Vp_Ringtoneplaybtn.PlaySound( vpbtn, position);

            }
        });
        return v;
    }

    public static Apples newInstance(String rgtvv) {
       s=rgtvv;

        Apples f16 = new Apples();

        return f16;
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (this.isVisible()) {
            // If we are becoming invisible, then...
            if (!isVisibleToUser) {
                Vp_Ringtoneplaybtn.Playstop();
                vpbtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_black_24dp);

            } else {
                // do what you like
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }


}
```

Comment: it´s hard to understand what you want

Comment: I am making ringtone app which have recycler view list...In recycler view there are names of ring tone with playpause toggle button...when I click on any item of recycler view it opens new fragment in viewpager...but I want only one fragment that  opens dynamically and show the data of clicked recycler item in fragment and I want when I swipe viewpager previous and next it shows data of recyclerview accordingly